# Iron Golem Spawner Blocks In air?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking to create an Iron Golem grinder on a factions server with literal "Iron Golem Spawner blocks." However, unlike in my previous experience, I cannot seem to get them to spawn in mid-air? I've seen multiple videos of the same design working but it for some reason just does not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what those blocks are, you'll need to explain what they actually are, what they do, how they work, etc.